# Add completion handler to presentViewControllerAsSheet(NSViewController)?

Tags: macos, swift, event-handling, nsviewcontroller

I am attempting to present a sheet configuration view (`AddSoundEffect`) for my main window/view controller (I'm using storyboards), and when the configuration view controller is dismissed, take the values entered in the `AddSoundEffect` view and pass that back to the main view. My current code in the main view controller:

```
presentViewControllerAsSheet(self.storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("AddSoundEffect") as! AddSoundViewController
```

And in the `AddSoundViewController.swift` file, the code to dismiss it is:

```
self.dismissViewController(self)
```

To pass the data, I have a class-independent tuple that I save data to. How do I add a completion handler to `presentViewControllerAsSheet`, and (optionally) is there a better way to pass the data between view controllers?

Setup: Xcode version 6.4, OS X 10.10.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Delegation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID276) pattern is the easiest way for you.

```
// Replace this with your tuple or whatever data represents your sound effect
struct SoundEffect {}

protocol AddSoundViewControllerDelegate: class {
  func soundViewController(controller: AddSoundViewController, didAddSoundEffect: SoundEffect)
}

//
// Let's say this controller is a modal view controller for adding new sound effects
//
class AddSoundViewController: UIViewController {
  weak var delegate: AddSoundViewControllerDelegate?

  func done(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Dummy sound effect info, replace it with your own data
    let soundEffect = SoundEffect()

    //
    // Call it whenever you would like to inform presenting view controller
    // about added sound effect (in case of Done, Add, ... button tapped, do not call it
    // when user taps on Cancel to just dismiss AddSoundViewController)
    //
    self.delegate?.soundViewController(self, didAddSoundEffect: soundEffect)

    // Dismiss self
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
  }
}

//
// Let's say this controller is main view controller, which contains list of all sound effects,
// with button to add new sound effect via AddSoundViewController
//
class SoundEffectsViewController: UIViewController, AddSoundViewControllerDelegate {
  func presentAddSoundEffectController(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let addSoundController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddSoundEffect") as? AddSoundViewController {
      addSoundController.delegate = self
      self.presentViewController(addSoundController, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
  }

  func soundViewController(controller: AddSoundViewController, didAddSoundEffect: SoundEffect) {
    // This method is called only when new sound effect is added
  }
}
```

Another way is to use closures:

```
// Replace this with your tuple or whatever data represents your sound effect
struct SoundEffect {}

//
// Let's say this controller is a modal view controller for adding new sound effects
//
class AddSoundViewController: UIViewController {
  var completionHandler: ((SoundEffect) -> ())?

  func done(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Dummy sound effect info, replace it with your own data
    let soundEffect = SoundEffect()

    //
    // Call it whenever you would like to inform presenting view controller
    // about added sound effect (in case of Done, Add, ... button tapped, do not call it
    // when user taps on Cancel to just dismiss AddSoundViewController)
    //
    self.completionHandler?(soundEffect)

    // Dismiss self
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
  }
}

//
// Let's say this controller is main view controller, which contains list of all sound effects,
// with button to add new sound effect via AddSoundViewController
//
class SoundEffectsViewController: UIViewController {
  func presentAddSoundEffectController(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let addSoundController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AddSoundEffect") as? AddSoundViewController {
      addSoundController.completionHandler = { [weak self] (soundEffect) -> () in
        // Called when new sound effect is added
      }
      self.presentViewController(addSoundController, animated: true, completion: {})
    }
  }
}
```

Or many other ways like sending notification, ... Whatever suits your needs. But delegation pattern or closures is the best way to go in this specific case.

---

I missed that your question is about `NSViewController`. This example is for iOS, but same pattern can be used on OS X without any issues.

Comment: I'm working with `NSViewController`s, not `UIViewController`s. Will this work the same way?

Comment: Yep, without any issues. These are common patterns used on both iOS and OS X.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to detect sheet opening or closing is to use the [Sheet Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Sheets/Tasks/SheetNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001047-BABFIBIA):

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows.first?.delegate = self
    }
    func windowDidEndSheet(notification: NSNotification) {

    }
    func windowWillBeginSheet(notification: NSNotification) {

    }
}
```