# How to use an NSAlert with storyboards

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm teaching myself Swift (currently using Xcode 7.3) and I'm working with storyboards for the first time. I'm writing an OS X-based app and I want to display an alert when the user attempts to load data when data already exists. I've read the following thread, [Add completion handler to presentViewControllerAsSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445785/add-completion-handler-to-presentviewcontrollerassheetnsviewcontroller) but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around closures/completion handlers. I understand them "in theory" but not yet well enough to write one.

In the thread above, a Struct is being returned. I just need to return an Int or Bool to indicate whether the user wants to overwrite the data or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a second view controller. Just configure and display an `NSAlert` object:

```
@IBAction func loadData(sender : AnyObject) {
    let dataAlreadyExists = true // assume this is always true

    if dataAlreadyExists {
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "Do you want to reload data?"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Reload")
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Do not reload")

        alert.beginSheetModalForWindow(self.view.window!) { response in
            if response == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn {
                // reload data
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't figure out how to get a reference to the window using storyboards.