# completion handler to presentViewControllerAsSheet OSX

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsviewcontroller

I am presenting `NSViewController` from another ViewController.

```
[self presentViewControllerAsSheet:secondViewController];
```

here is method of `NSWindow`

```
- (void)beginSheet:(NSWindow *)sheetWindow 
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSModalResponse returnCode))handler;
```

Is there any equivalent method to above For `NSViewController` with completion handler.

Comment: Please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445785/add-completion-handler-to-presentviewcontrollerassheetnsviewcontroller. It's for Swift but the pattern is the same.

Comment: i have already go through it. but I want to know is there any other way or apples method like - (void)beginSheet:(NSWindow *)sheetWindow 
 completionHandler:(void (^)(NSModalResponse returnCode))handler; for NSViewController

Comment: No, there is no API with a completion handler, you have to write your own logic.

Comment: thanks vadian for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this enough?

```
class SOMEViewController: NSViewController {
    private var parentWindow : NSWindow? = nil

    public func beginSheetModal(for parentWindow: NSWindow, 
                                handler : @escaping (NSApplication.ModalResponse) -> Void) {
        self.parentWindow = parentWindow
        guard let sheet = self.view.window else { return }

        parentWindow.beginSheet(sheet, completionHandler: handler)
    }

    public func endSheet(_ response : NSApplication.ModalResponse) {
        guard let parent = self.parentWindow else { return }
        guard let sheet = self.view.window else { return }

        parent.endSheet(sheet, returnCode: response)
    }
```